# Добавить текст в строку

Tags: c#, строки

Есть такая задача: добавить переменную secretCode в строку такого типа 
    OBR|1|      Источник//001011//A11.00.00.111//1.1.1^TSI|100011^SHAPIRO|A10.10.001.101^текстпро    извольнойдлины^^111Б^текстпроизвольнойдлины|||20110610092100| **+ secretCode +**|||||^||текстпроизвольнойдлины|^||Y8359833Fg=|||||||||^^^^^|||||||

Скажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: Конкатенация? https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms228504.aspx

Comment: В примере я показал как должно быть сделано (да, с помощью конкатенации), по умолчанию строка без + secretCode +, и вопрос в том как эту переменную добавить именно в то место, в котором она находится в примере

Comment: Уточните свой вопрос, неясно, что вы хотите. Также вы не указали, что пробовали и что у вас получалось.

Comment: Знаю, что вроде как можно через регулярки, но моя проблема в их непонимании.

Comment: У вас в вопросе есть желаемый результат, но нет исходных данных. Поэтому вам предложили конкатенацию, как самое простое решение. Если оно не подходит, тогда нужны исходные данные. Кстати, я могу ошибаться, и приведенная в вопросе стока и есть исходные данные, а secretCode это метка где вставить код. В таком случае подойдет метод String.Replace, без всяких регулярок.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример со String.Replace(). Вот смотрите, объясню на просто примере: у вас есть строка "13" и переменная 2. Необходимо добавить переменную(2) в строку между 1 и 3, чтобы получилось 123.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас текст с разделителями. SecretCode явно в определенной "ячейке" должен быть.
Разбейте по разделителю, замените содержимое определенной ячейки, склейте назад.

```
var secretCodeIndex=8;
var elements=data.Split('|');
elements[secretCodeIndex]=secretCode;
data=string.Join("|",elements);
```

http://ideone.com/MCVoT7

Comment: Благодарю вас!)